# comparing categories of data from one column to another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to coding and I cannot seem to find the answer to this problem online.

I am trying to compare two sets of data for a data science project.

I am comparing one column which could be either two types of categories; 'recurrence-events' or 'no-recurrence-events', to another column which is 'Age bracket' which has five categories.

I would like to find the relationship between the two and find the amount of rows that fall under each category.

below I have posted a screenshot of the outcome from a website that has done a similar project to the one I am doing using a dataset from the UCI Repository.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could put a sample of the data. Otherwise, it es difficult to understand what your problem is and what your desired result is.

However, I can understand that you have two categorical columns and you would want to get the number of rows in each of the combinations.

The following might help you.

```
import pandas as pd

# asuming that the DataFrame name is df and the columns are ['column1', 'column2']
pd.crosstab(df['column1'], df['column2'])
```